# Clear All Functions inside a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 JQuery functions inside a DIV.  One by one, if I click on each text inside the red border (div), the text will turn to a different color and other action takes place.  After clicking on all text, I want to reset all text to initial setup by clicking on "Reset all" at the bottom.

Problem: a function in "Reset all" doesn't work.
It should reload elements inside the red border, not the entire page.

Please help.  Thanks!

[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6tzLqk4b/2/)

HTML

```
<span class="yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,</span>
<div class="red-border">
   <div class="turn-red">
     Turn me red
   </div>
   <div class="turn-blue">
     Turn me blue.<span class="text-add">text is added</span>
   </div>
   <div class="turn-green">
     Turn me green
   </div>
</div>
<div class="reset">
Reset all
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//let originalState = $('.red-border').html();
$('.turn-red').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
$('.turn-blue').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'blue');
  $('.text-add').fadeIn();
});
$('.turn-green').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
$('.reset').click(function() {
    $('.red-border').load();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try with this function

```
$('.reset').click(function() {
  $('.red-border div').each(function(){
    $(this).css('color','black');
  });
});
```

I am sorry, my English is not so good.

Comment: `$('.red-border div').css('color','black');` does the exactly same. No need to `.each()` with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio! but I wanted to reset all JQuery functions.